Keep getting unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED while trying to use proxies with selenium-wire
I'm trying to use proxies while using selenium-wire but I keep getting the following error message while trying to access a webpage :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/beta.py", line 36, in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/")
  File "path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 363, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "path\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "path\Miniconda\envs\geoweb_doctorat\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C5B8FDA5+29557]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5B02240]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59BB6EA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59B3746]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A4439]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A61E2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A46FF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A3FAD]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A3ECA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A1D52]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59A23CC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C59BE821]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A596CE]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A374FA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A588A3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A372A3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A012DF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5A02451]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C5EBDCBD+3363469]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C5F09B47+3674391]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C5EFEAEB+3629243]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C5C4FC66+815670]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5B0D6EF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5B092B4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5B09450]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C5AF81FF]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9888D7034+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF988B02651+33]

This is how I set up my script :
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
proxy = f"http://{username}:{password}@ca.smartproxy.com:20000"
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f"http://{username}:{password}@ca.smartproxy.com:20000",
        'https': f"https://{username}:{password}@ca.smartproxy.com:20000"
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
)

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/")
time.sleep(5)

I'm not sure why it's not working. I checked multiple blog post and my script seems fine.
